# Drafted page gets updated when added new page in Wordpress within WP-Engine

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I am facing an wiered problem while adding new Page in the wordpress.

**Steps:**

1. Create a new page with title "Test one" and save it in the draft.
2. Immediately create another page with title "Test two" and save it in draft.
3. Observe that page with title "Test one" is not visible in the drafts section, only "Test two" is visible.

***I have also observed the post id assigned to the page after save. The post id for the two pages was same while saving it. (now it shows only latest one.)***

> **The first page gets updated by the second one because of the same post id.**
>
> **The same behaviour is occurred with Posts as well.**
>
> **Can anybody explain why wordpress behaving like this and do not allow to add new page?**

I have searched over an internet about the issue and read that for SEO the site should have handle duplicate contents for SEO.

> Is this the case that's why wordpress not allowing to create new page
>   with similar title?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was created because of Cache-Control header which was set in the .htaccess file.

Due to this edit-post.php is getting served from the disk cache.

> The problem gets resolved.

One more quick question if anybody has answer to this.

> Is it recommended to set headers in the .htaccess or do we have to set
>   it in any other place?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your issue with fresh wordpress working well

May other plugin causes issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I have already tried with deactivating all the plugins but still same behaviour.
For reference 
WordPress Version: 5.5.1
AND Active Theme : Twenty Twelve